# Show an immersion is locally one to one using the inverse function theorem

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential, smooth-manifolds

Using the inverse function theorem, show that an immersion is locally one to one.

I am really struggling with this homework question can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: The differential of the immersion is injective. Can you extend your function to a function whose differential is bijective? Then apply the inverse function theorem.

Comment: how can we extend the function? does this mean if f:Rm -> Rn, where m < n, extend f to another function F : Rn -> Rn? Could we do this by just adding n-m zeroes to the end of f?

Comment: Well, that is roughly the idea. Zero's don't work however, since you want to make sure that the differential is invertible to apply the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Try an example!